# Running Fragment Transaction Stops the application as soon as it opens

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I remove the .commit() in the transaction the app compiles but shows an empty screen. If I add .commit() the app opens and closes instantly. I am new to fragments can anyone help resolve this. I have simply added an ImageView layout. Infalted it in Fragment class and hardcoded an image in it. Further I just created an instance of that Fragment in MainActivity.

**My Android Studio version is:  3.1.3**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:id="@+id/head_container"
/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

body_part_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/body_part_frag"
>

</ImageView>
```

BodyPartFragment.java

```
 package com.example.musa.my_frag_app;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BodyPartFragment extends Fragment {

public BodyPartFragment(){
    //Do Nothing
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container);
    ImageView body_image = rootView.findViewById(R.id.body_part_frag);
    body_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

  return rootView;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.musa.my_frag_app;

  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BodyPartFragment headfrag = new BodyPartFragment();
    FragmentManager frag_m = getSupportFragmentManager();
    frag_m.beginTransaction().add(R.id.head_container,headfrag).commit();
    //frag_m.executePendingTransactions();
}
}
```

Comment: try `replace()`.

Comment: Nope. Same result.

Comment: Can you paste the error log?

Comment: @AmineNokra there is no error. It just closes. Application doesn't crash. it just closes the activity.

Comment: @VinayRathod There is no reason why this image shouldn't be displayed

Comment: @VinayRathod I tried the solution below with text. That also doesn't work

Comment: @MaazBinMusa `inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container);` will definitely throw an exception. The default for `LayoutInflator.inflate()` is `attachToRoot=true`. It should be `false` when called from `onCreateView` in a `Fragment` as this handles that for you. Change to `inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container, false);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container);` will definitely throw an exception. The default for `LayoutInflator.inflate()` is `attachToRoot=true`. It should be `false` when called from `onCreateView` in a `Fragment` as this handles that for you. Change to `inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container, false);`

Answer (score 1):

add param for attachToRoot `false`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container, false);
    TextView body_text = rootView.findViewById(R.id.body_part_frag);
    body_text.setText("Hello World");
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Still does the same thing. Closes the application

Answer (score 0):

Try This for fragment body part:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/body_part_frag"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How would this work. I need a container in the Activity main.

Comment: This layout is not for `MainActivity` it is for `body_part_fragment.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
BodyPartFragment headfrag = new BodyPartFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.head_container, headfrag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

change

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, container);

to

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body_part_fragment, null);